# Casting values in F#

Tags: f#

I have the following and I need to call the "functiontocall" in another script but need to constrain the inputs to ints. However the maths in the functions it calls all need float types.

```
let functionone (x: float) (y :float) = x/y

let functiontocall (a: int) (b: int) = functionone a b 
                                        |> functiontwo 
                                        |> functionthree
```

What would be the best thing to do to cast these as float?

Answer (score 1):

Casting in F# is just using the type name in an expression:

```
 functionone (float a) (float b)
```

Comment: It should be noted that not all casting is as simple as that.